# Direct descendants only with jQuery's find()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is it possible to select only direct descendants of an element using jQuery's `find()` or `children()` functions?

I have several `ul` elements, each with other `ul` elements inside them, and some root `li` elements too. I store a specific parent `ul` in a variable (as a jQuery object) and then look for any of the root `li` elements within using: `my_root_ul.find('li');`.

However, this method also finds any `li` that belongs to the `ul` inside the `ul`, if that makes sense.

My question is, how can I select only direct descendants of type `li` within the `my_root_ul` object using `find()`. Ordinarily, we could use something like `$('ul > li')` to return only direct `li` elements, but it must be possible to filter down the returned elements?

Here is an example to demonstrate what I mean:

```
<ul>
    <li>I want this
        <ul>
            <li>I don't want this</li>
            <li>I don't want this</li>
            <li>I don't want this</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>I want this</li>
    <li>I want this</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you want `my_root_ul.children("li")`?

Comment: You already found `children()`, that should be the right function.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Like this:

```
my_root_ul.find('> li');
```

`.children()` also selects only the immediate children, so you can use that also:

```
my_root_ul.children('li');
```

Comment: Wow, I never knew that was possible. Thanks!

Comment: `my_root_ul.childNodes` perhaps?

Comment: That wouldn't work as `my_root_ul` is a jQuery collection, not a DOM object.

Comment: You don't even need the selector on the `children` call -- the **only** valid immediate descendants of `ul` elements are `li` elements.

Comment: "my_root_ul.find('> li');" That's gold right there. Didn't even know that was an option!